# R Panel data reorder rows based on character variable

Tags: r, string

My data looks something like:

```
VarA    VarB    VarC
1   Paris   9
2   Paris   8
3   Paris   5
1   Boston  8
2   Boston  4
3   Boston  5
1   Miami   6
2   Miami   4
3   Miami   5
1   Dallas  8
2   Dallas  3
3   Dallas  7
```

I need to order VarC following an arbitrary order of values of VarB (non alphabetical) and also the order of VarA. It should look like:

```
VarA    VarB    VarC
1   Miami   6
2   Miami   4
3   Miami   5
1   Paris   9
2   Paris   8
3   Paris   5
1   Dallas  8
2   Dallas  3
3   Dallas  7
1   Boston  8
2   Boston  4
3   Boston  5
```

Target order:

```
target <- c("Miami", "Paris","Dallas","Boston")
```

What I have tried:

```
df[match(target,df$VarB),]
```

and also

```
test1 <- df[rownames(target),,drop=FALSE]

test2 <- df[order(target),]
```

The `match` function didn't work either because it is panel data and there are several "Miami" and "Paris" and it seems to break down when there is repetition of Variable B values.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dat$VarB <- factor(dat$VarB, levels=target)
dat[order(dat$VarB, dat$VarA),]
#       VarA   VarB VarC
#7     1  Miami    6
#8     2  Miami    4
#9     3  Miami    5
#1     1  Paris    9
#2     2  Paris    8
#3     3  Paris    5
#10    1 Dallas    8
#11    2 Dallas    3
#12    3 Dallas    7
#4     1 Boston    8
#5     2 Boston    4
#6     3 Boston    5
```

Comment: +1 for the same train of thought.... I guess `ordered = TRUE` is overkill in my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make "VarB" an ordered factor?

```
factor(mydf$VarB, target, ordered = TRUE)
#  [1] Paris  Paris  Paris  Boston Boston Boston Miami  Miami  Miami 
# [10] Dallas Dallas Dallas
# Levels: Miami < Paris < Dallas < Boston
order(factor(mydf$VarB, target, ordered = TRUE))
#  [1]  7  8  9  1  2  3 10 11 12  4  5  6
mydf[order(factor(mydf$VarB, target, ordered = TRUE)), ]
#    VarA   VarB VarC
# 7     1  Miami    6
# 8     2  Miami    4
# 9     3  Miami    5
# 1     1  Paris    9
# 2     2  Paris    8
# 3     3  Paris    5
# 10    1 Dallas    8
# 11    2 Dallas    3
# 12    3 Dallas    7
# 4     1 Boston    8
# 5     2 Boston    4
# 6     3 Boston    5
```

---

Add `mydf$VarA` in there to order by that too.